# How to add array of ids in a query with many to many relationships Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 entities and one for n:m relationship:

```
const Item = db.define('item', {
   id: {
       type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
       primaryKey: true,
       autoIncrement: true,
   },

   title: Sequelize.STRING,
   description: Sequelize.STRING,

   price: {
       type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
       defaultValue: 0.0,
   },
});

const Category = db.define('category', {
   id: {
       type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
       primaryKey: true,
       autoIncrement: true,
   },
   title: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const ItemCategory = db.define('item_category', { 
   id: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
     primaryKey: true,
     autoIncrement: true,
   },
   category_id: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT
   },
   item_id: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT
   }
});
```

And relations:

```
Category.belongsToMany(Item, { 
  through: {
    model: ItemCategory,
    unique: false
  },
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  constraints: false
});

Item.belongsToMany(Category, { 
   through: {
     model: ItemCategory,
     unique: false
   },
   foreignKey: 'item_id',
   constraints: false
});
```

Association is working fine(I guess). But when I try to query `Item`, the result comes without categories field.
Also I can add `include` option and it returns category objects:

```
Item.findAll({ include: [{ model: Category }] })
```

The QUESTION IS: How to associate ONLY categories_ids when querying Item objects to have something like this in response:

```
{
   id: 1,
   categories_ids: [1,3,4],
   price: 20
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually do that because of how data of nested associations are arranged by default.

Suppose you did

```
Item.findOne({
 where: { item_id: 1}, 
 include: [{
  model: ItemCategory,
  as: 'categories_ids',
  attributes: ['category_id']
 }]
})
```

You will get

```
{
    id: 1,
    categories_ids: [
        { category_id: 1 },
        { category_id: 2 },
        {...},
        {...}
    ],
    price: 20,
}
```

Of which you can probably re-arrange the information, which involves the process of something like this:

```
let pojo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

pojo.categories_ids.forEach(function(el, index) {
    pojo.categories_ids[index] = el.category_id
})
```

Comment: thanks, in `then` closure got plain objects from sequelize entities using `item.get({ plain: true })` and replaced categories field the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
associate your through model directly to item as well so you can include in query

```
Item.hasMany(ItemCategory, { 
   foreignKey: 'item_id',
   constraints: false
});

Item.findAll({ 
 include: [{
  model: ItemCategory,
  as: 'categories_ids',
  attributes: ['category_id']
 }]
});
```

Comment: in this case we still have array of objects, but with only one param - category_id, but not array of raw ids